# Layout preview not matching emulator or phone

Tags: android, user-interface, layout

I am having this problem when I run my calculator app on my phone or emulator, all the buttons, text views and other widgets go all over the place and it looks messy. Even the theme of the app doesn't show. I will provide images from both views:

Layout preview mode:

[image: Click on here to see it.]

Emulator/phone:

[image: CLick to see it.]

See the difference. I don't know how to fix this!

I will include  .xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/number1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="number1"
    android:inputType="number"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/number2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/switch2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/number2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="419dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="number2"
    android:inputType="number"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView9"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/number1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sum"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:textSize="11.9dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.005"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/number2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="43dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="+"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button6"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button2"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button4"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sum"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.636"
    android:background="#fed136"

    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="43dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="-"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button19"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button20"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button6"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button8"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
    android:background="#fed136"

    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="43dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="X"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button19"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/button2"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.035"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/sum"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
    android:background="#fed136"

    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="43dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="/"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/button10"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/number2"
    android:background="#fed136"

    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="43dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="SQ"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button6"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button6"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button10"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.09"
    android:background="#fed136"

    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_width="53dp"
    android:layout_height="42.9dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="SR"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/ratingBar"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button9"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button10"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button3"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.008"
    android:background="#fed136"

    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button8"
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="376dp"
    android:text="C"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button20"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/switch3"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
    android:background="#fed136"

    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button9"
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="43dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="E"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button19"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button19"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.968"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button10"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button2"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
    android:background="#fed136"

    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button10"
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="43dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="%"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button4"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
    android:background="#fed136"

    />

<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:rating="5"
    android:stepSize="5"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.492"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button19"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button18"
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="43dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="sin"

    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button19"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button8"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
    android:background="#fed136"


    tools:text="sin" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button19"
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="43dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"

    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="cos"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/button20"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button20"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
    android:background="#fed136"


    tools:text="cos" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button20"
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="43dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"

    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="tan"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.824"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/number1"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.126"
    android:background="#fed136"

    tools:text="tan" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/ratingBar"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.148"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button10"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.028" />

<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/switch2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
    android:background="#fed136"


    android:text="Radians"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/number1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/switch3"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/number1" />

<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/switch3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="44dp"
    android:text="Degree"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button8"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/switch2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:background="#fed136"

    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="75dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="75dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    android:text="Radient"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/sum"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView10"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/number2" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView10"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
    android:text="Degrees"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView9"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/switch3" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: remove `tools:layout_editor_absoluteY`

Comment: What do I replace it with

Comment: I did that, still didn't do anything

Comment: refresh layout view. because your code indicate your phone design right,

Comment: you need to learn basics about andriod layouts, check this to start with https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/

Comment: You have a alot of constraints wrongly set

Comment: How do you refresh

Comment: You are 11 year old programmer, if I am right :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally never been a fan of ConstraintLayout and it feels easier and dynamic to use Linear & Relative layouts.

Here is one example of how you can construct this layout where it will be the same regardless of screen.

Here is how it looks like (disregard the black background, I couldn't be bothered to change the global style for text color)

[image: https://i.imgur.com/vzNnnuX.png]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_view_normal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:baselineAligned="false">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/number1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="number1"
                android:inputType="number" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/number2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="number2"
                android:inputType="number" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <ToggleButton
                    android:id="@+id/switch2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#fed136"
                    android:text="Radians"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView9"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Radians"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView9"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/switch3" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <ToggleButton
                    android:id="@+id/switch3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Degree"
                    android:background="#fed136" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView10"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Degrees"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView9"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/switch3" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="+"
            android:background="#fed136"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="-"
            android:background="#fed136"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="x"
            android:background="#fed136"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="/"
            android:background="#fed136"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="SQ"
            android:background="#fed136"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="SR"
            android:background="#fed136"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="C"
            android:background="#fed136"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button9"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="E"
            android:background="#fed136"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button10"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="%"
            android:background="#fed136"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button18"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="sin"
            android:background="#fed136"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button19"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="cos"
            android:background="#fed136"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button20"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="tan"
            android:background="#fed136"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sum"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:numStars="5"
            android:rating="5"
            android:stepSize="5"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The downside here, not counting the naming of your views, would be that very small screens will squeeze the buttons to be slimmer. I would recommend maybe using something like GridView, or maybe FlexBox.

Comment: @Raghav you are new to Android, you should learn LinearLayout and RelativeLayout first like this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just press the magic button in android studio which is present at design widow of android studio. This is for constraints state updating to current latest changes

Comment: Still didn't do anything

Comment: still stayed the same